# Doea there exist a holomorphic function satisfying a specific condition

Tags: complex-analysis

> Does there exist a holomorphic function $f$ on
> $D:=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ s.t
> $$f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\dfrac{n^2}{n^2+1}\quad\forall n\geq 1.$$

Actually, I'm able to solve this problem in the case $D=\mathbb{C}$. Here are my thoughts in case $D=\mathbb{C}$.
Consider $g(z)=(z^2+1)f(z)$. From hypothesis, $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and $g\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=1$. Since $\left\{\dfrac{1}{n}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ converges to $0\in\mathbb{C}$ when $n\to\infty$, we conclude $g=1$ by [Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).
$\Rightarrow (z^2+1)f(z)=1$. However, if we put $z=i$, we get $0=1$ (Absurd!)
Hence there is no such holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$.
Could someone help me in the case $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: construct an entire function $g$ st $g(n)=\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$ by your favorite method (interpolation, Weierstrass etc) and put $f(z)=g(1/z), z \ne 0$

Comment: @Conrad why we need to put $f(z)=g(1/z)$?

Comment: to get the condition $f(1/n)=g(n)=\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$; we know by general theory (and easy to construct directly by interpolation when the sequence is bounded say) that we can get entire functions satisfying $g(n)=a_n$ for any sequence $a_n$

Comment: @Conrad How to construct such $g$? How can you ensure such $g$ exists?

Comment: this is a general theorem of complex analysis - follows from Mittag Leffler and Weierstrass in general (for any $|z_n| \to \infty$ and any $a_n$ there is entire $g$ st $g(z_n)=a_n$ and more generally you can also  make $g'(z_n)=b_n$ and any finitely many number of derivatives for any $z_n$ to be whatever you want)  but here one can easily construct directly $f(z)=\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi}(\sum_{n \ge 1}(-1)^na_n(\frac{1}{z-n}+\frac{1}{n}))$ which is easy to show that is entire when $a_n$ bounded and satisfies $f(n)=a_n$ which is a "minimal" such $f$ in a sense

Comment: @Conrad your $f$ does not sastify $f(n)=a_n$.

Comment: $f(n)$ is $(-1)^na_n$ times the limit as $z\to n$ of $\sin \pi z/(\pi(z-n)$ which I think is $(-1)^n$ eg by doing the Taylor series